# GoCardless Direct Debit integration for CiviCRM: will this extension handle 5 year memberships?

Tags: wordpress, gocardless

CiviCRM 5.31.0 - Wordpress 5.5.3 - PHP 7.3.24

---

I help run an organisation (non-profits) where we have individual memberships, lasting for 1, 2 and 5 years and where subscriptions are being currently collected, mainly through PayPal.  We are looking to create a further contribution page(s) to accept direct debits and see this extension as a possible solution.  Before trialling it, does anyone know please whether it and GC would cope with memberships of more than 1 year, where of course the interval between DD's could be anything up to 5 years?

Comment: Could you sepcify what you mean by direct debit, e.g. Sepa Payments?!

Answer (score 1):

I think thats perfectly possible within GoCardless. You would need to setup a plan for each of the differing membership collection periods you would like to collect for in order to use it as a traditional Direct Debit. FYI a Direct Debit is a UK equivelant of SEPA with some technical differences i.e. UK bank accounts only etc.